# How can I import files when running a CGI script?

Tags: cgi, python-3.7

I have an HTML form that submits a POST request to cgi-bin/output.py. I want to extract the data from the form and then manipulate it using imported functions from other files.

This is on Windows command prompt, running Python 3.7 and using the CGI module. I have followed instruction on other posts in regard to how to import files (_init_py, using importlib.util) but I think this may be a CGI specific problem.

```
<!--index.html-->
<form class="formBox" action="cgi-bin/output.py" method="post">
  <select name="dropdown" autofocus/>
```

```
#output.py
import cgi, cgitb
import tagging
from urllib.request import urlopen  

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
dropdown = form.getvalue('dropdown')
tagging.tagger(dropdown) #call function from different file on argument from HTML form
```

The tagging.py file is in cgi-bin along with output.py. I want to be able to use a function from tagging.py but when I try to import the file I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it? If both files are in the same directory, it should work.
I just tested it on Windows 10, and it works as expected.